# when using setState () appears setState () callback argument returned a Future

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

when I use setState () the text appears in the debug console..

> setState() callback argument returned a Future.
>   The setState() method on _LoginActivityState#9cd91 was called with a closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
>   Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().

```
   Future<void> login() async {
final formState = formKey.currentState;
if (formState.validate()) {
  formState.save();
  try {
    final response = await UserController.login({
      "username": username,
      "password": password,
    });

    if (response != null && response["success"]) {
      setState(() async {
        accessToken = response['token'];
        //print(token);
        if (accessToken != null) {
          await Http.setAccessToken("Bearer $accessToken");
        }
        print('$accessToken');
        final getMe = await AiframeworkController.getProfile();
        print('data: $getMe');
        if (getMe != null && getMe['is_verified'] == true) {
           return Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainActivity()));
        } else {
          return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: You should probably do the async code outside of the setState method and only set the state when that code has completed

Answer (score 15):

setState() should be used only to set the new state of a stateful widget. You shouldn't perform *async* operations in it and you shouldn't return anything from it. I am assuming that 'accessToken' is the field you are changing the state of so it will be better to do all of the other operations outside the setState() and just leave `'accessToken = response['token'];'` inside.

Comment: The only exception I've come across is for a re-usable FutureBuilder.  You might want the Future<T> to actually be the state, eg, a list with a refresh button that shows a spinner when pressed until loaded

Comment: @TheTrav How would I go about updating the Future<T> state variable used in my Futurebuilder? (Since this: `setState(() => _futureForFutureBuilder = myFuture);` throws exactly this error..

Comment: @Jimmy I never ended up with a satisfactory solution.  https://gist.github.com/thetrav/bca10c1fd1dd123fe5dbbd7c361aabff is the collection of components I use to deal with different async use cases.

In the case of future builder i try to provide the future as a prop so the widget gets re-built when the async function is re-run

Comment: @jimmy I should disclaim that my solution still appears to be setting the future as part of the build function, which is a no-no according to the flutter docs, however I haven't experienced any issues with it.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16218#event-3407922515 has some further discussion but it's mostly over my head

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory.

In your code, you are using the `async` keyword:

```dart
 setState(() async {
        accessToken = response['token'];
```

However, if you have asynchronous operations, you should handle them *outside* of `setState()` and *then* call `setState()` to update the UI with the new state.

You can usually use [MyFuture.`whenComplete`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/whenComplete.html):

```dart
_myFuture()
    .whenComplete(() => setState(() {}));
```